# Animation flickering in ANDROID

Tags: android, animation, flicker

I am trying to implement something relatively simple in ADNROID. I have a bunch of Drawables stored in a list. I want to create an effect where the drawables are displayed on top of each other, one by one, using a fade-in effect.

I have had partial success with the code below. It actually works flawlessly on my phone (Nexus S), but it shows flickering on my tablet (ASUS TF101). This is probably due to the fact that the tablet has a faster CPU.

Here is my setup: I have stored all the Drawables in the `drawables` list. I have also defined two images in my layout, one on top of the other: `imageViewForeground` and `imageViewBackground`.

The idea is to set the background image first, then start an animation where the foreground image starts from alpha-0 and goes to alpha-1. Then replace the background with the new foreground image, choose a new foreground (i.e. the next drawable) and loop forever.

The `counter` object is a simple wrapper for an int counter.

Here is my code:

```
final Animation fadeInAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0f, 1f);
fadeInAnimation.setDuration(2000);
fadeInAnimation.setStartOffset(3000);
fadeInAnimation.setFillBefore(false);
fadeInAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
fadeInAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
fadeInAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
fadeInAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        imageViewForeground.setImageDrawable(drawables.get(counter.value()));
        Log.d(TAG, "onAnimationStart");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAnimationEnd");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        imageViewBackground.setImageDrawable(drawables.get(counter.value()));
        counter.increase();
        // the problem appears in this line, 
        // where the foreground becomes visible for a very small period, 
        // causing the flickering
        imageViewForeground.setImageDrawable(drawables.get(counter.value()));
    }
});

imageViewForeground.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
```

Any ideas how I can overcome this flickering problem?

Comment: Have you check the Android API samples about animation ? I think you use-case is covered. http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html

Comment: Let me add that I also tested it on another phone (Nexus Galaxy) and it also works flawlessly there. I am wondering if this is an issue with this particular tablet (ASUS TF101).

Comment: I looked at the samples in the past. I will have another look at them. But still I am wondering if there is something wrong in my code or maybe a bug in ANDROID/ASUS TF101 software.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug on the tablet if it's okay on Nexus Galaxy

Comment: Yes I am beginning to think that this might be an issue with this particular setup (ANDROID 4 on ASUS TF101).